# Varnish caching and brute force failed logins not detected

Tags: authentication, varnish, brute-force, varnish-4

Since I installed and set up varnish caching, failed logins are being logged to auth.log with the IP of the cache (127.0.0.1) instead of the attacker. e.g.

`Jul  8 14:48:06 host wordpress(hostname.com)[7285]: Authentication failure for admin from 127.0.0.1`

In my config Varnish serves HTTP, HTTPS is served from apache2 both as the reverse proxy and the backend webserver. Internal and external web requests are logged separately.. All appears working correctly, except brute force logins are now not being picked up by fail2ban as they all appear to originate from the server.

sub vcl_recv is set to 'pass' the login pages;

```
if (req.url ~ "/wp-(login|admin)") {
return (pass);
        }
```

How can I get the requesting IP logged to auth.log instead of 127.0.0.1 ?

Answer (score 1):

Varnish keeps track of the client IP and stores it in a `X-Forwarded-For` header, that it forwards to your backend.

It's just a matter of adding that header to your `LogFormat` to include `X-Forwarded-For`.

This is what the `combined` and `common` log formats looks like in your Apache config file:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
```

You'll have to change it as follows:

```
LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
```

Instead of the *client IP address*, the value of the `X-Forwared-For` header will be stored in your logs.

## UPDATE

As it turns out, the log items in question are not related to Apache. The suggestion to modify the `LogFormat` is irrelevant.

This is likely related to the use of `wp-fail2ban`, a WordPress module that logs failed login attempts in the system's `auth.log` file.

Because `wp-fail2ban` is not aware of Varnish, the IP address it logs is always `127.0.0.1`. However the [`WP_FAIL2BAN_PROXIES`](https://docs.wp-fail2ban.com/en/4.2/defines/constants/WP_FAIL2BAN_PROXIES.html) configuration parameter can make this module *proxy aware*.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had made similar changes to the back-end and enabled mod_remote, my apache2 log format actually is;
`LogFormat "%a %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined`
`LogFormat "%a %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common`
As I said in my question, the apache logging is correct (i.e. the remote address is logged, not varnish) but I still get 127.0.0.1 recorded in auth.log for failed logins.

Comment: @anorcross I guess auth.log is not part of Apache, so its format is defined elsewhere.Where is this auth.log on your filesystem, and who is responsible for writing to it? Is it WordPress itself, or just Linux. Depending on the answer to that question, we'll know where to look for the formatter.

Comment: @anorcross are you using wp-fail2ban for logging authentication failures? If that is the case, you might want to have a look at https://docs.wp-fail2ban.com/en/4.2/defines/remote-ips.html

Comment: I think you're right. I'm using wp-fail2ban so that will be responsible for the entries in auth.log. I'll test out adding WP_FAIL2BAN_PROXIES and report back.